# Is there a way to change the data elements so my code will basically begin from the start anytime I initiate a method with a constructor?

Tags: java, methods, constructor, integer

Good evening, the question is already in the title.

I was wondering what to change, so my program will calculate the treetrunk correctly, show the correct amount of stars & dots for the second runthrough and also execute the for-loops for the tree trunk.

Below you can see the main Test Class and the one containing all the other elements and methods.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = sc.nextInt();

        while (n % 2 == 0 || n < 0) {    //Reject even numbers

            n = sc.nextInt();       //Read the input
            System.out.println("Please type in a uneven number");
        }


        /**
         * First runthrough for length 9
         */

        Triangle_new triangle = new Triangle_new(n);

        triangle.display_triangle(); //Call Triangle method

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total number of stars = " + (triangle.get_stars() / 2));
        System.out.println("Total number of dots = " + (triangle.get_dots() / 2));
        System.out.println();


        Triangle_new tree = new Triangle_new(n);   //Constructor for triangle with tree trunk

        tree.display_tree();     //Call tree method


        System.out.println();


        /**
         * Second runthrough for length 11
         */

        System.out.println("Now the length will be set to 11.");
        System.out.println();


        Triangle_new triangle2 = new Triangle_new(n);

        triangle2.set_length(11);

        triangle2.display_triangle(); //Call triangle method

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total number of stars = " + (triangle2.get_stars() / 2));
        System.out.println("Total number of dots = " + (triangle2.get_dots() / 2));
        System.out.println();


        Triangle_new tree2 = new Triangle_new(n);  //Constructor for triangle with tree trunk

        tree2.set_length(11);
        tree2.get_lines();

        tree2.display_tree();    //Call tree method

    }
}
```

Here is the class containing the methods and data elements.

```
public class Triangle_new {

    int stars = 1;
    int dots;
    int lines;
    int length;
    int dotsCounter;
    int starsCounter;
    int linesCounter;
    int starsnew = 1;
    private int tree_trunk;

    //Main constructor
    public Triangle_new(int n) {

        this.length = n;

        while (stars <= length) {
            linesCounter++;                     // Number of lines

            dots = (length - stars) / 2;        //Calculation of dots

            for (int i = 1; i <= dots; i++) {
                dotsCounter++;                  //Total of dots
            }             


            for (int i = 1; i <= stars; i++) {
                starsCounter++;                 //Total of stars
            }            

            for (int i = 1; i <= dots; i++) {
                dotsCounter++;
            }

            stars = stars + 2;             //Calculate stars
        }
        stars = starsCounter;
        dots  = dotsCounter;
        lines = linesCounter;
    }

    //Triangle method
    public void display_triangle() {
        while (starsnew <= length) {
            linesCounter++;
            dots = (length - starsnew) / 2;

            for (int i = 1; i <= dots; i++) {
                dotsCounter++;
                System.out.print(".");
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= starsnew; i++) {
                starsCounter++;
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= dots; i++) {
                dotsCounter++;
                System.out.print(".");
            }

            starsnew = starsnew + 2;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void set_length(int l) {
        this.length = l;
    }

    //Print out triangle with tree trunk
    public void display_tree() {

        int dotstreetrunk;

        dotstreetrunk = (length - stars) / 2;

        display_triangle();


        tree_trunk = (lines / 2);


        for (int i = 1; i <= dotstreetrunk; i++) {
            dotsCounter++;
            System.out.print(".");
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= tree_trunk; i++) {
            starsCounter++;
            System.out.println("*");

        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= dotstreetrunk; i++) {
            dotsCounter++;
            System.out.print(".");
        }


    }

    public int get_length() {
        return length;
    }

    public int get_lines() {
        return linesCounter;  //Number of lines
    }

    public int get_stars() {
        return starsCounter;  // Number of stars
    }

    public int get_dots() {
        return dotsCounter;   //Number of dots
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move your code out of constructor into set_length() method, and then call it from constructor. That way you are reusing code

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: Of course. From here it seems like your computation is placed in the constructor, and it seems that you would like the computation to run each time the setLength method is called. If you place the code in setLength, then you achieve this in your code, and by calling it in constructor you complete the exercise

Comment: I understand. Would you mind showing me exactly how to integrate it?

It irritates me a bit, because I used two variables to manipulate the length, 'n' in the beginning and 'l' in the set_length method.

So I'm not really sure how to do it correctly.